# Is there a container in Boost or C++11 which act as a queue but with unique elements?

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

I'm looking for a container like `std::queue` which will add elements (e.g. a custom class with field `id` of type `uint`) at the end, but *only* if that object is not already inside the container.

Two elements of my class are to be considered equal only when `id` is equal (I have overloaded operator `==`).

Does such a container exist in C++11 or perhaps in Boost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is called queue with conflation. The naive implementation is to use something like this:

```
std::set<your_key_t> unique;
std::queue<your_data_t> q;

void enqueue(your_data_t x) {
    if (unique.insert(x.key).second) {
        q.push(std::move(x));
    }
}

your_data_t dequeue(your_data_t dflt) {
    if (!q.empty()) {
        your_data_t x = std::move(q.front()); q.pop();
        unique.erase(q.front().key);
        return x;
    }
    else return dflt;
}
```

A less naive implementation may be merging incoming data with the one in the queue in some non-trivial way (say overwriting) instead of just dropping updates.

Comment: Nice idea, +1. But since OP asked for C++11, `unordered_set` would almost certainly be better since it has O(1) insertion, search, and removal. Also, `set` requires that OP define `operator <`, which is probably not hard, but not the same as `operator ==` which he already defined.

Comment: Changing this to use `unordered_set` is trivial, and the idea is clearly explained.

Comment: @SchighSchagh - you should be very careful when blindly suggesting `unordered_map` having non-deterministic access latency, when claiming it is `O(1)` when in fact it is `O(N)`, and when forgetting that the key to have corresponding `std::hash<key_t>` (or custom) defined in order to be used with `unordered_map`

Comment: Two remarks: (1) It's `unique.erase()` (and not `unique.remove()`). (2) To get the strong exception safety guarantee (provided that `your_data_t` move constructor (if it exists) allows it) swap the lines `unique.erase(q.front().key);` and `your_data_t x = std::move(q.front());`.

Comment: @bobah It's not a blind suggestion. Yes, worst case is O(N), but average case is O(1) with a good hash. In OP's case, he is using `uint` for the key, so `std::hash<uint>` will do just fine. Although there may certainly be pathological cases where `unordered_set` would perform worse than `set`, those are extremely rare and/or contrived in practice. Btw, `set` has non-deterministic access latency too (half the nodes are at depth `log(n)`, the other half are not; tree may need to be rebalanced, etc.).

Comment: @SchighSchagh `set` guarantees no worse than O(lg(n)) performance for every operation.  Rebalancing must occur as you go along, you cannot do a "rare expensive rebalancing".  `unordered_set` does not.  Despite this, as noted, `unordered_set` has such a lower constant factor that it is almost always way faster.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22256154/873025), here's another example of how you can combine [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)<sup>*</sup> and [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) to form a container with the properties you're looking for.

```
template <typename T>
class QueueUnique {
public:
    void push(T t) {
        if (set_.insert(t).second) {
            queue_.push(std::move(t));
        }
    }
    T& front() { return queue_.front(); }
    T& back() { return queue_.back(); }
    typename std::set<T>::size_type size() { return set_.size(); }
    /* More functions */
private:
    std::set<T> set_;
    std::queue<T> queue_;
};
```

Use like so:

```
QueueUnique<int> q;
q.push(1);
q.push(1);
q.push(2);
q.push(3);
q.push(1);

std::cout << "Size: " << q.size() << std::endl;   // Size: 3
std::cout << "Front: " << q.front() << std::endl; // Front: 1
std::cout << "Back: " << q.back() << std::endl;   // Back: 3
```

<sub>* *Note: `std::set` requires that the operator `<` for the element type is defined.*</sub>

Comment: Why do you need the argument of `push()` to be an rvalue reference